# Logstash doesn't filter out JSON from the Twitter API

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to remove unnecessary fields. There are many of them. I'm using JSON filter plugin for Logstash but it doesn't work properly. It doesn't want to filter the data or just doesn't send it to the output.
I've tried to use the `mutate` field but without success.
I want to remove for example the `entities` field which is a top-level field but none of my configs are working. I also want to remove some nested fields...

Here's my example JSON from the Twitter API:

```
{
  "retweet_count": 0,
  "created_at": "Mon Dec 14 18:43:09 +0000 2020",
  "place": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "lang": "pl",
  "filter_level": "low",
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "id": 1338555139993591800,
  "id_str": "1338555139993591814",
  "quote_count": 0,
  "is_quote_status": false,
  "geo": null,
  "entities": {
    "symbols": [],
    "user_mentions": [],
    "urls": [
      {
        "indices": [
          117,
          140
        ],
        "url": "xxx",
        "expanded_url": "xxx"
      }
    ],
    "hashtags": [
      {
        "text": "koronawirus",
        "indices": [
          84,
          96
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "COVID19",
        "indices": [
          97,
          105
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "Lockdown",
        "indices": [
          106,
          115
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "timestamp_ms": "1607971389183",
  "reply_count": 0,
  "retweeted": false,
  "text": "W Wielkiej Brytanii wykryto nowy wariant koronawirusa. Kolejne kraje z lockdownem­čĹç\n\n#koronawirus #COVID19 #Lockdown\n\nxxx",
  "contributors": null,
  "truncated": false,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "source": "<a href=\"xxx">Twitter Web App</a>",
  "@timestamp": "2020-12-14T18:43:09.000Z",
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "favorited": false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "user": {
    "created_at": "Tue May 12 09:11:01 +0000 2009",
    "profile_use_background_image": false,
    "lang": null,
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "profile_text_color": "000000",
    "id": 39464882,
    "id_str": "39464882",
    "following": null,
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
    "is_translator": false,
    "protected": false,
    "profile_image_url": "xxx",
    "profile_link_color": "3B94D9",
    "name": "Salon24.pl",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
    "favourites_count": 309,
    "profile_background_image_url": "xxx",
    "followers_count": 17473,
    "description": null,
    "location": "Polska",
    "url": "xxx",
    "profile_background_color": "000000",
    "utc_offset": null,
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "xxx",
    "default_profile": false,
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "verified": false,
    "translator_type": "none",
    "friends_count": 1028,
    "time_zone": null,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "screen_name": "Salon24pl",
    "profile_image_url_https": "xxx",
    "statuses_count": 48490,
    "notifications": null,
    "listed_count": 203,
    "profile_background_tile": false
  },
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "@version": "1",
  "coordinates": null
}
```

And here's my actual config:

```
input {
  twitter {
      id => "logstash_to_kafka_plugin"
      consumer_key => "xxx"
      consumer_secret => "xxx"
      oauth_token => "xxx"
      oauth_token_secret => "xxx"
      keywords => [ "koronawirus" ]
      full_tweet => true
      ignore_retweets => true     
    }   
  }

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        remove_field => [ "[message][entities]"]
        }
}

output {
      kafka {
        codec => json
        topic_id => "twitter_tweets"
      }
    }
```

I've tried different ways to indicate that field like:

```
remove_field => [ "entities" ] or
remove_field => [ "[entities]" ]
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: The JSON will get added at the root level, so you will not have a [message][entities] field.  remove_field => [ "entities" ] should work.

Comment: remove_field=>["entities"] didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a mutate filter with remove_field after the json filter block so the new mutate filter executes after the fields have been cretaed to the root via the json filter.
Your filter could look something like

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message" 
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["entities", "user.created_at"] // works for nested field as well
    }
}
```